# apply function in pandas to create two columns

Tags: python, pandas, split, apply

I have a Pandas DataFrame called `ebola` as seen below. `variable` column has two pieces of information `status` whether it is *Cases* or *Deaths* and `country` which consists of country names. I try to create two new columns `status` and `country` out of that `variable` column by using `.apply()` function. However, since there are two values I am trying to extract, it does not work.

[image: ebola dataframe]

```
# let's create a splitter function
def splitter(column):
    status, country = column.split("_")
    return status, country

# apply this function to that column and assign to two new columns
ebola[['status', 'country']] = ebola['variable'].apply(splitter)
```

The error I get is

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

**I want my output to be like this**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

```
ebola[['status','country']]=ebola['variable'].str.split(pat='_',expand=True)
```

Comment: It does not work. It creates a column `(status, country)`. It is just one column and values are `Cases, Guinea` which is pretty interesting. The instructor used a different method similar to yours. But I wanted to go with creating a **function** then use it through `.apply()` method.

Comment: I think it worked. Thank you. Sorry for the first response, please ignore that. This is better, one liner.

Answer (score 0):

This is very late post to original question. Thanks to [@ansev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11884237/ansev), the solution was great and it worked out great. While I was going through my question, I was trying to develop a solution based on my first approach. I was able to work it out and I wanted to share for anyone who might want to see a different perspective on this.

update to my code:

```py
# let's create a splitter function
def splitter(column):
    for row in column:
        status, country = row.split("_")
        return status, country

# apply this function to that column and assign to two new columns
ebola[['status', 'country']] = ebola['variable'].to_frame().apply(splitter, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Two updates to my code, so it could work.

1. Instead of going through Series, I converted it to dataframe using [`.to_frame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) method.
2. In my `splitter` function, I had to iterate through each row since it was a DataFrame. Therefore, I added `for row in column` line.

To replicate all of this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create the data
ebola_dict = {'Date':['3/24/2014', '3/22/2014', '1/15/2015', '1/4/2015'],
              'variable': ['Cases_Guinea', 'Cases_Guinea', 'Cases_Liberia', 'Cases_Liberia']}
ebola = pd.DataFrame(ebola_dict)
print(ebola)

# let's create a splitter function
def splitter(column):
    for row in column:
        status, country = row.split("_")
        return status, country

# apply this function to that column and assign to two new columns
ebola[['status', 'country']] = ebola['variable'].to_frame().apply(splitter, axis=1, result_type='expand')

# check if it worked
print(ebola)
```